# Is there any downside/difference to Pkunk being absorbed by Yehat?

Tags: star-control-2

When you speak to Pkunk in the beginning, they declare that they are planning to go to Yehat.

If you take too long to start Yehat civil war (by showing them Shofixty) they will inform you that Pkunk were "absorbed" - as you can see by Pkunk circle on star map disappearing.

If you already got Clear Spindle and 4 Pkunk ships by that point, **is there any downside or difference** in the further gameplay from Pkunk being "absorbed" into Yehat pre-civil-war?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From experience, I can say that there is no difference.

**MAJOR SPOILER BELOW**

> The Pkunk re-appear near the end of the story in either event.

Comment: I just finished replaying Ur-Quan Masters, LOST Yehat to the revolution, and they reappeared at the end. You are 100% correct.